# MongoTemplate : group by on multiple fields with max operator

Tags: java, mongodb, mongotemplate

Want to convert following query to Java Mongo template aggregation but don't know how to write multiple fields in group operator with max operator condition.

```
db.getCollection('mycollection').aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$somefield.$id",
      xyz: {
       "$max": "$_id"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

tried to find on mongodb forums, and other website but no solution.

Comment: Can you add what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use:

```java
Aggregation.group("somefield.id").max("_id").as("xyz");
```

And you can get the data with something like this:

```java
// Create aggregation step
AggregateOperation groupOperation = Aggregation.group("somefield.id").max("_id").as("xyz");

// Create aggregation object
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(groupOperation);

// Run the aggregate query
AggregationResults<YourClass> result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "mycollection", YourClass.class);

// Get result as list
List<YourClass> listResult = result.getMappedResults();
```